# How to SUM a column value in MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I am new to mssql ,Here I need to SUM a column values.

But in my case have some joins between the tables finally I have a column with 2 rows of output .

What I want to do is I want to SUM the final output of my query.

This is my query :

```
 SELECT 
               SUM(ESCD.ITEM_QTY) * ((SELECT COLOC_PROD_PRICE
               FROM LOM_LNK_PROD_COMP 
               WHERE  COLOC_PROD_CODE = ITEM_ID)
               /
             ((SELECT LMUL.UOL_CONV_QTY 
               FROM LOM_MST_UOM_LINK AS LMUL

               JOIN LOM_MST_PRODUCT AS LMP 
               ON LMUL.UOL_MAIN_UOM_CODE = LMP.PROD_STOCK_UOM
               AND LMP.PROD_CODE = ESCD.ITEM_ID)/LMUL.UOL_CONV_QTY )) AS 'TOTAL_AMOUNT'



               FROM EC_SHOPPING_CART_DETAIL AS ESCD

               JOIN LOM_MST_UOM_LINK AS LMUL
               ON LMUL.UOL_MAIN_UOM_CODE = ITEM_PACK_SIZE

               WHERE CREATED_BY = 'xyz'
               AND  CHECK_OUT = 'FALSE'
               GROUP BY ITEM_ID,LMUL.UOL_CONV_QTY
```

Output :

[image]

Expected AS :

[image]

can anyone help me to solve this .

Comment: Please include sample data here.  It is difficult to decipher your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
SELECT
  SUM(X.TOTAL_AMOUNT) AS 'TOTAL_AMOUNT'
FROM
(
 SELECT 
           SUM(ESCD.ITEM_QTY) * ((SELECT COLOC_PROD_PRICE
           FROM LOM_LNK_PROD_COMP 
           WHERE  COLOC_PROD_CODE = ITEM_ID)
           /
         ((SELECT LMUL.UOL_CONV_QTY 
           FROM LOM_MST_UOM_LINK AS LMUL

           JOIN LOM_MST_PRODUCT AS LMP 
           ON LMUL.UOL_MAIN_UOM_CODE = LMP.PROD_STOCK_UOM
           AND LMP.PROD_CODE = ESCD.ITEM_ID)/LMUL.UOL_CONV_QTY )) AS 'TOTAL_AMOUNT'



           FROM EC_SHOPPING_CART_DETAIL AS ESCD

           JOIN LOM_MST_UOM_LINK AS LMUL
           ON LMUL.UOL_MAIN_UOM_CODE = ITEM_PACK_SIZE

           WHERE CREATED_BY = 'xyz'
           AND  CHECK_OUT = 'FALSE'
           GROUP BY ITEM_ID,LMUL.UOL_CONV_QTY
) X;
```

Comment: it is working for me thanks ,can you please tell what is 'X' and how it works @AnkurPatel

Comment: It is called derived table. If you search on google `derived table in sql` you will find a lot of information regarding them. Also, please accept the answer if it solves your issue. Thanks.

Comment: To give you just an idea, I just made the output of your query into a table named `x`. You can actually name it whatever you want and then just use it after `from` just like an actual table.